# When to sever and repot a baby orchid?

Tags: repotting, orchids

I have an orchid that has produced a "baby" on a former flower spike. The baby orchid has 4 leaves (2 small, 2 medium), and some nice & healthy-looking aerial roots. The roots are all growing perpendicular to the direction that the leaves are facing.

How will I know when it's ready to be separated from the parent? And what's the best way to do this? How should I pot this small orchid (pot size, potting medium, nutrients, etc...)?

UPDATE: Added pictures

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: A picture would help, can you post one?

Comment: @kevinskio: Sure, I'll try to get one up here tomorrow.

Comment: @kevinskio: Pics have been added.